# How to install the same user on two different servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, user-management, windows-authentication

**I have two Windows Server 2008 servers.**

**1)** Is a web server

**2)** is a db server

I need to use **Windows authentication** to access the db server, **therefore 
I need to create a new user on both machines.**

I'm finding user domains quite confusing. Help or tips would be awesome.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a active directory domain & are your computers members of the domain?

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure :(

Comment: both machines are member of the same domain! yes!

Comment: If both are on the same domain, you should be able to access the db using the credentials defined by Active Directory. If you are using SQL Server, you will need to add the \\domain\user to the security of the database for access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your application pool (assuming IIS web server) on the web server to run under a domain account DOMAIN\YourApplicationId, then add DOMAIN\YourApplicationId to the SQL server as a logon and grant the account rights on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the same user in both computers works for desktop OS like XP or 7, but not for domains.

Since you are using a domain, you need to create the user in the domain, not local users in both computers (if you don't use it I don't think that you can use Windows authentication, since that doesn't provide enough security).

The whole point of a domain is having a single set of users so you can set permissions easier for all the computers and resources of the domain.

Also, check that the network connection is properly configured (we have problems in our office network because some computers didn't use the domain server as the gateway, which is needed in our domain configuration).